# Use typeahead.js on multiple inputs on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using typeahead.js from Twitter. `http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/`

And I am trying to use multiple inputs on the same page. One input is loaded initially on the page. And then the others are added upon user request by clicking a button.

I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is, the inputs are getting added after the script for the typeahead.js has already been initialized. So they are not getting the information they need.

I tried manually adding a second input and it worked just fine, that is why I have come to the above conclusion.

I also tried wrapping the typeahead.js javascript in a function and calling that when the input is added but that disabled the first input and made my page look funky. Although, the second input did then work like it is supposed to.

My code is below:

```js
function addRow() {
  addTableRow($('.table tbody'));
}

function removeRow() {
  var par = $(this).parent().parent();
  var tableSize = $('.table tbody tr').length;
  if (tableSize == '1') {
    alert('You must have one row');
    return false;
  }
  par.remove();
};

function calculateRow() {
  var par = $(this).parent().parent();
  var price = $(par).find('.price').val();
  var qty = $(par).find('.qty').val();
  var total = price * qty;
  $(par).find('.total').val(total.toFixed('2'));
}

$('.table tbody').on("click", ".removeRow", removeRow);
$('.table tbody').on("blur", ".qty", calculateRow);

function addTableRow(table) {
  $(table).append(
    "<tr>" +
    "<td><input name='item_number[]' type='text' class='form-control'></td>" +
    "<td><div class='the-basics'><input class='typeahead form-control' type='text' name='item_name[]''></div></td>" +
    "<td><input name='item_price[]' type='text' class='form-control price'></td>" +
    "<td><input name='item_qty[]' type='text' class='form-control qty'></td>" +
    "<td><input name='item_total[]' type='text' class='form-control total'></td>" +
    "<td class='text-center' style='vertical-align:middle;'><a href='#' class='text-success removeRow'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a></td>" +
    "</tr>");
}

var items = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {
    url: '/admin/items/fetch_items/',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(item) {
        return {
          name: item
        };
      });
    }
  }
});

items.initialize();

$('.the-basics .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'items',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: items.ttAdapter()
});
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item #</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Price</th>
      <th>Item Qty</th>
      <th>Item Total</th>
      <th class="text-center">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo form_input( 'item_name[]', '', 'class="form-control"'); ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="the-basics">
          <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" name="item_name[]">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo form_input( 'item_price[]', '', 'class="form-control price"'); ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo form_input( 'item_qty[]', '', 'class="form-control qty"'); ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo form_input( 'item_total[]', '', 'class="form-control total"'); ?>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">
        <a href="#" class="text-success removeRow">
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **remote** instead.

```
var items = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
        url: '/admin/items/fetch_items/',
        filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list, function(item) {
                return {
                    name: item
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```